# Micronaut + Angular : Refresh page

Tags: java, angular, micronaut

I'm building an application with Micronaut and Angular 4.

I've configured  the Micronaut to  Serving Static Resources

```
micronaut:
    router:
        static:
            resources:
                enabled: true
                mapping: /**
                paths: classpath:public
```

Everything works well (*DefaultURL route:http://localhost:8080/dashboard*). 
The Angular app is loaded and the user interacts with the app and navigate through the routes correctly.

In the controller I configured the server to redirect to index.html.If the path does not exist in the server.

```
@Get("/{[path:[^\\.]*}")
    @Secured(SecurityRule.IS_ANONYMOUS)
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public HttpResponse<?> refresh() {
        return HttpResponse.redirect(URI.create("/index.html"));
    }
```

But when the user refreshes the page (e.g. pressing F5).

If the current Url is *"http://localhost:8080/userdetails/status"* after refresh the Angular app goes to the default route *"http://localhost:8080/dashboard"*,
instead of the route which the user was in *"http://localhost:8080/userdetails/status"*

Please help me on this
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the Working Code below which I have been implemented.

```
@Controller("/")
public class IndexController {
    @Inject
    ResourceResolver res;


    @Get("/{[path:[^\\.]*}")
    @Secured(SecurityRule.IS_ANONYMOUS)
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public HttpResponse<?> refresh(HttpRequest<?> request) {
        StreamedFile indexFile = new StreamedFile(res.getResource("classpath:public/index.html").get());
        return HttpResponse.ok(indexFile);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're redirecting to `/index.html`. The information from the previous request is lost. Instead of redirecting you should instead render the html directly.

There are several tools to do so including using the `resourceResolver` to resolve the html on the classpath. You can return a `StreamedFile` instance to render the stream to the response.

The resolver can be injected and you would construct the streamed file yourself.

https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/api/io/micronaut/core/io/ResourceResolver.html
https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/api/io/micronaut/http/server/types/files/StreamedFile.html

Comment: Can you please guide me on some sample code how to handle in controller or any bean class  to resolve this.It will be very helpful. thankyou

Comment: @naveen It's quite simple, the `getResource` method returns a `URL` which you can use to construct the `StreamedFile`.

Comment: @james-kleehThanks for your guidance. Now the problem is resolved.I have posted my answer