# Micronaut and Angular 8

Tags: angular, single-page-application, micronaut

i have a Angular App as static content with a micronaut backend (2.0.0-M3).
Everything secured with an external keycloak. Language Kotlin on Java 11 and Gradle.

I followed that Guide: https://guides.micronaut.io/micronaut-spa-react/guide/index.html 
and also had a look on that [Micronaut + Angular : Refresh page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52630974/micronaut-angular-refresh-page)

But at the end i could not bring everything together.

Having that config works:

```
micronaut:
  router: 
    static-resources:
      default:
        enabled: true
        mapping: "/**"
        paths: "classpath:static"
  security:
    enabled: true
    intercept-url-map:
      - pattern : /api/**
        access:
          - isAuthenticated()
      - pattern : /static/**
        access:
          - isAnonymous()
      - pattern : /**
        access:
          - isAnonymous()
```

That works so far. But if i bring in an IndexController like

```
@Controller("/")
public class IndexController {
    @Inject
    ResourceResolver res;


    @Get("/{[path:[^\\.]*}")
    @Secured(SecurityRule.IS_ANONYMOUS)
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public HttpResponse<?> refresh(HttpRequest<?> request) {
        StreamedFile indexFile = new StreamedFile(res.getResource("classpath:public/index.html").get());
        return HttpResponse.ok(indexFile);
    }
}
```

I get compile errors cause path is not there and if i add an optional path, he could not load the css and javascript files.

Would be happy if someone could help.
Oliver

Comment: Is the compile error coming from `@Get("/{[path:[^\\.]*}")`?

Comment: yes ist from the path:

Comment: Can you be more specific about "I get compile errors cause path is not there and if i add an optional path, he could not load the css and javascript files." ? This controller isn't handling css and javascript files either way because it excludes paths that contain a period

Comment: Also what Micronaut version?

Comment: Also you have an extra `[`

Comment: I used the 2.0.0.M3 but have some issues with the http client so i got back to 1.3.5 and after removing the [ everything works fine.